# Android - simple user input form web-view to back-end java with jQuery Mobile

Tags: java, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, webview

I am currently designing a native android application. I am planning to use jQuery Mobile web view as my interface and do all the calculations with java back-end. (still deciding using phonegap or not)

I have some difficulties implementing a page that allows a user to fill in a form and pass the variable to the android java part.

Researching all morning, I have learned how to interact between javascript/html and java with addJavascriptInterface(). But the only thing I can find that answer my question is with JSON. That seems a little complicated.  Is there a way I can pass the variable as a parameter of a java function?

(I learned that if I do not use a web view, I can simply use getText() or getSelectedItem() with default UI to do what I want to)

I apologize there is no code avaliable, since this is still in designing stage, and I am a little new to android sdk.

Thanks

Comment: What data do you need to pass into the javascript interface? How many fields on the form and what type? You could simply create a delimited string and call a function on the interface.

Comment: looks like its going to be around 5 user setting fields.  By that does it mean that when the submit button is clicked simply make a javascript function save those input values into variables and call a java function?

Comment: See my example answer. Only just started playing with this stuff myself but I think you can pass multiple parameters into the `JavaScriptInterface` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, here's an example of interacting with the javascript interface...

Setting the javascript interface in your Activity...

```
JavascriptInterface javasriptInterface = new JavascriptInterface(this);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(javasriptInterface, "Android");
```

The inner JavascriptInterface class in your Android Activity...

```
public class JavascriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavascriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public boolean doSomething(String name, String address) {
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Your form will have various input fields. Example...

```
<form name="myForm" ...>
    <input type=text name=personName>
    <input type=text name=personAddress>
    <input type="button" value="Do it" onClick="callDoSomething()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function callDoSomething() {
        var theName = document.myForm.personName.value;
        var theAddress = document.myForm.personAddress.value;
        var result = Android.doSomething(theName, theAddress);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. I have actually seen it elsewhere and I understand this part.  What I don't understand thou is how should I pass the input values into the Android.showTast? (i.e. how do i get the form input values into "message" ?(  thanks

Comment: See my edit at the end of my answer and also that I've added the `doSomething(...)` function to the `JavascriptInterface` class further up. As I said I'm fairly new to doing this stuff but it hopefully will give you a start.