# Html Checkbox in android webview

Tags: android, html

I want to know:-

In my project i am using html content and displaying them in android webview. and i am using eclipse ide. this is tiny code.

```
"<form name =\"frm\">"+
                                                "<input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"First\" value =\"xyz\">xyz<br>"+
                                                "<input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"First\" value =\"abc\">abc<br>"+ 
                                               "</form>"
```

my question is how can i get check box state .its checked or unchecked.

or how can i catch the state in my java code.

UPD:-

```
 public String html =  "<form name =\"frm\">"+
                                                    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"First\" value =\"xyz\">as<br>"+
                                                    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"Second\" value =\"zyx\">as<br>"+ 
                                                    "<input type =\"button\" onclick =\"callDoSomething()\"><br>"+
                                                    "</form>" +


                                                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
                                                    "function callDoSomething() {"+
                                                    " var theName = document.frm.First.value;"+
                                                    "alert('theName ')"+
                                                    "}"+
                                                    "</script>";
```

Comment: You can use java script interface in your Activity.. Check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961418/android-simple-user-input-form-web-view-to-back-end-java-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: thanks for ans. i want to know how i ll get checked or unchecked state

Comment: Yes you put onclick listener for the checkbox and get the state from javascript to your java

Comment: in eclipse i dont things so we can write js . couse it takes html as string right.

Answer (score 0):

First, both of your checkboxes are named "First", you should probably name second one "Second". If you want to search checkboxes by value - just add a simple js for loop.

Assuming you want to get the results from your Android code (as opposed to JS event like clicking a button), here's how you get Java boolean value for you checkbox by name:

```
// assuming your activity is MyActivity, target checkbox name
// is in the targetCheckboxName var and webView has the document
// loaded already
Object jsi = new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String reportCheckboxState(String name, boolean isChecked) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setMessage(name + " is " +
                isChecked).create().show();
    }
};
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsi, "injection");
webView.loadUrl(
    "javascript:injection.reportCheckboxState(frm." + targetCheckboxName +
    ".name, frm." + targetCheckboxName + ".checked);"
);
```

But really, it's a very simple trick. Judging by comments to the question, you should probably read up on JavaScript and [WebView.addJavaScriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks Ivan .but same question ..it is possible write java script in .java class i am using ECLIPSE IDE and  my all html is is .java class.

Comment: Err.. I don't get it :) You're writing an Android app, right? The code in my answer is Java code. It has a JavaScript snippet in it – the one that's called by `webView.loadUrl("javascript: ... ");` It's just like executing a JS snipped from a browser's address bar - you put `javascript:` in front of it. Or do you want to have the JS code in a separate HTML file or something?

Comment: please see update previous i was using same code to display html in webview but now i need to get checkbox state .i am trying to do like see my update.

Comment: Actually, no, I dont get it still :) I assume you don't have a problem with getting the checkbox values and displaying them in an Alert in JavaScript, right? Do you want to deliver the state of all checkboxes to your Java code when user pushes the HTML button? In your update, you call a Java function (`Android.doSomething()`) from JS and then display the value returned by Java call in JavaScript, when you could have just used JavaScript for all of that, without the call to `Android.doSomething()`. So I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Can you be more clear about it?

Comment: Ivan forget about Android.doSomething ,except it my code is fine according to you. right. means it ll written in string form only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25064/discussion-between-cobra-hissss-hissss-and-ivan-bartsov)