# How to get Visual/Partial Text from WebView?

Tags: android, ios, css, uiwebview, android-webview

Before posting this question I have searched a lot on this, however couldn't find any work around problem.

I have a screen with webview, I have configured webview with following settings:
1.WebPage can't scroll vertically or horizontally , 
2.Removed Zoom-In & Zoom-Out on webview

The HTML file which is displayed in webview has long text & using CSS3 content is devided into multiple columns that only accommodate screen size, displaying only that split content or say partial content from HTML page (**not whole HTML page**). Now I have to get that split content from webView from Java (Android) & objective-C (iOS) side **without screen touch or long press**, from CSS3 & JS I am not able to get it.

**Is it possible to get visual text / content from webview ?**

If anybody have faced such problem or knows any solution please reply it.

**I am facing this problem for both Android & iOS app.**

Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the DOM with jquery, and merge the results, appending them to a hidden field.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Then you could get that field from objective c, like this:

```
NSString *myFields = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.form1.myFields.value"];
```

For Android, you could try this:

[Android - simple user input form web-view to back-end java with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961418/android-simple-user-input-form-web-view-to-back-end-java-with-jquery-mobile)