# set/get Data in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this webview:

```
<textarea name="text" id="textPage" class="text_area"></textarea>
<script language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
//call some method of javascript.
</script>
```

Is it possible to set text to textarea and get text from textarea.
Set/get data from id(if any method possible) will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to set up a JavaScript interface. This answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961418/android-simple-user-input-form-web-view-to-back-end-java-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: To get data from a WebView in Android : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76415649/12272687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research i found solution, it might useful in future:

**Set Data:**

***Android:***

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:setData()");
```

***JS:***

```
function setData(){
//js code
}
```

**Get Data:**

***Android:***

```
JavascriptInterface jsInterface = new JavascriptInterface(MainActivity.this);
converterWeb.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");//android is a tag.
```

class:

```
public class JavascriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        JavascriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public boolean getData(String name) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Text: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

***JS:***

```
Android.convertedText(value);//send data in tag.
```

better option still welcome.